# ElevateZoom zoom window inside modal popup displays behind content prior to popup opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

Up against a looming deadline and find myself totally stuck on the following - I've now spent four days on it, without much progress, so any help or suggestions much appreciated!

I'm using multiple instances of ElevateZoom (with gallery and lightbox on, taken from their Examples page, each inside it's own modal pop-up, on the [same page - WARNING it's a lingerie shop - someone on here complained last time.)](http://badsekta.com/trix/shop.html)

My problem is that the zoom window appears before a modal is opened, and if I simply set the zoom functionality to 'false', it seems to make the clickable area of the product images narrower too! The zoom is meant to be on the main product image inside each modal.

I've messed about with various z-indexes, done a lot of Googling, referred to the official config, various posts on here, and a few elevate-zoom-specific z-index tutorials that were relevant but didn't change anything (can't post more links as my reputation isn't high enough yet), and I'm still utterly stuck...

HELP!

HTML -

```
<div class="content-table">
  <table width="528" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="middle"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Welcome to Guerilla Geisha" width="504" height="139"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="middle"><strong style="color: #F00">PANTIES</strong> - Please click a design for more details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><!-- COPY FROM HERE TO MAKE A NEW PRODUCT POPUP --> 
        <a href="#openModal"> <img src="assets/img/shop-images/cherry-blossom-knickers-1.jpg" alt="Cherry Blossom panties - Front view" width="176" height="189" border="3" > </a>
        <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <div id="column1-wrap">
          <div id="column1">
            <div class="zoom-left">
              <div style="height:350px;width:350px;" > <img style="border: 3px solid #fff; position: absolute;" id="zoom_03" src="elevatezoom-master/images/small/cherry-blossom-knickers-1.jpg" data-zoom-image="elevatezoom-master/images/large/cherry-blossom-knickers-1.jpg" width="350"> </div>
              <br>
              <div id="gallery_01" style="width=" 350pxfloat:left;="" "=""> <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery active" data-update="" data-image="elevatezoom-master/images/small/cherry-blossom-knickers-1.jpg" data-zoom-image="elevatezoom-master/images/large/cherry-blossom-knickers-1.jpg"> <img src="elevatezoom-master/images/thumb/cherry-blossom-knickers-1.jpg" ></a> <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="elevatezoom-master/images/small/cherry-blossom-knickers-2.jpg" data-zoom-image="elevatezoom-master/images/large/cherry-blossom-knickers-2.jpg"><img src="elevatezoom-master/images/thumb/cherry-blossom-knickers-2.jpg" ></a> <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="elevatezoom-master/images/small/cherry-blossom-knickers-3.jpg" data-zoom-image="elevatezoom-master/images/large/cherry-blossom-knickers-3.jpg"> <img src="elevatezoom-master/images/thumb/cherry-blossom-knickers-3.jpg" > </a> <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="elevatezoom-master/images/small/cherry-blossom-knickers-4.jpg" data-zoom-image="elevatezoom-master/images/large/cherry-blossom-knickers-4.jpg"><img src="elevatezoom-master/images/thumb/cherry-blossom-knickers-4.jpg" ></a> </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#zoom_03").elevateZoom({gallery:'gallery_01', cursor: 'pointer', galleryActiveClass: "active", imageCrossfade: true, loadingIcon: "http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif"}); 

$("#zoom_03").bind("click", function(e) {  
  var ez =   $('#zoom_03').data('elevateZoom');
  ez.closeAll(); //NEW: This function force hides the lens, tint and window 
    $.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
  return false;
}); 

}); 

</script> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="column2">
          <div style='z-index: 1'>
            <h1>CHERRY BLOSSOM PANTIES</h1>
          </div>
          <div style='z-index: 2'>
            <p>A classic style brief gathered at the front and back for extra figure enhancing, finished to high standards, with 3 covered buttons at the front and frilly mesh elastic.</p>
            <p> The fabric is a truly soft, silky, sheer figure hugging stretch satin, printed with my design of Japanese inspired cherry blossom flowers.</p>
            <p>The briefs are luxurious, sexy and sassy while being really comfortable.</p>
          </div>
          <div style='z-index: 3'>
            <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
              <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
              <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@test.com" />
              <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB" />
              <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Cherry Blossom knickers" />
              <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Knick-001" />
              <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="23.00" />
              <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
              <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
              <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
              <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
              <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
              <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Choose from 5 colours:" />
              Choose from 5 colours:
              <select name="os0">
                <option value="Black">Black </option>
                <option value="Lime Green">Lime Green </option>
                <option value="Purple">Purple </option>
                <option value="Red">Red </option>
                <option value="Teal Blue">Teal Blue </option>
              </select>
              <br>
              <br>
              <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Choose from 4 sizes:" />
              Choose from 4 sizes:
              <select name="os1">
                <option value="XS (UK 6, US/CANADA 4, EUROPE 34, AUSTRALIA 8, JAPAN 7)">XS (UK 6, US/CANADA 4, EUROPE 34, AUSTRALIA 8, JAPAN 7) </option>
                <option value="S (UK 8, EUROPE 36, USA/CANADA 6, AUSTRALIA 10, JAPAN 9)">S (UK 8, EUROPE 36, USA/CANADA 6, AUSTRALIA 10, JAPAN 9) </option>
                <option value="M (UK 10, EUROPE 38,USA/CANADA 8, AUSTRALIA 12, JAPAN 11 )">M (UK 10, EUROPE 38,USA/CANADA 8, AUSTRALIA 12, JAPAN 11) </option>
                <option value="L (UK 12, EUROPE 40, USA/CANADA 10, AUSTRALIA 14, JAPAN 13)">L (UK 12, EUROPE 40, USA/CANADA 10, AUSTRALIA 14, JAPAN 13) </option>
              </select>
              <br>
              <br>
              <input name="submit" type="image" class="btn hover" alt="ADD TO CART" border="0" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS (Modal) -

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Product pop ups */

.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(100,100,100,0.8);
    z-index: 999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 900px;
    height: 458px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 13% auto;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.close {
    background: #fff;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background: #ae55ed;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#column1-wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
#column1 {
    width: 355px;
    float: left;
}
#column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 524px;
    margin-left: -524px;
}
```

CSS (Zoom) -

```
 #gallery_01 img{border:3px solid white;width: 78px;}
   #gallery_02 img{border:3px solid white;width: 78px;}
   #gallery_03 img{border:3px solid white;width: 78px;}
  #gallery_09 img{border:3px solid white;width: 78px;}
 .active img{border:3px solid #ae55ed !important;}


/* Hover */
@-webkit-keyframes hover {
 50% {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
 transform: translateY(-3px);
}
 100% {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
 transform: translateY(-6px);
}
}
 @keyframes hover {
 50% {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
 transform: translateY(-3px);
}
 100% {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
 transform: translateY(-6px);
}
.hover {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.hover:hover, .hover:focus, .hover:active {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
    transform: translateY(-6px);
    -webkit-animation-name: hover;
    animation-name: hover;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

JS -

Full version exceeds character limit, it's on my webspace [here](http://badsekta.com/trix/elevatezoom-master/jquery.elevatezoom.js).

I think this is the relevant section though?

```
$.fn.elevateZoom = function( options ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var elevate = Object.create( ElevateZoom );

        elevate.init( options, this );

        $.data( this, 'elevateZoom', elevate );

    });
};

$.fn.elevateZoom.options = {
        zoomActivation: "hover", // Can also be click (PLACEHOLDER FOR NEXT VERSION)
  zoomEnabled: true, //false disables zoomwindow from showing
        preloading: 1, //by default, load all the images, if 0, then only load images after activated (PLACEHOLDER FOR NEXT VERSION)
        zoomLevel: 1, //default zoom level of image
        scrollZoom: false, //allow zoom on mousewheel, true to activate
        scrollZoomIncrement: 0.1,  //steps of the scrollzoom
        minZoomLevel: false,
        maxZoomLevel: false,
        easing: false,
        easingAmount: 12,
        lensSize: 200,
        zoomWindowWidth: 400,
        zoomWindowHeight: 400,
        zoomWindowOffetx: 0,
        zoomWindowOffety: 0,
        zoomWindowPosition: 1,
        zoomWindowBgColour: "#fff",
        lensFadeIn: false,
        lensFadeOut: false,
        debug: false,
        zoomWindowFadeIn: false,
        zoomWindowFadeOut: false,
        zoomWindowAlwaysShow: false,
        zoomTintFadeIn: false,
        zoomTintFadeOut: false,
        borderSize: 3,
        showLens: true,
        borderColour: "#888",
        lensBorderSize: 1,
        lensBorderColour: "#000",
        lensShape: "square", //can be "round"
        zoomType: "window", //window is default,  also "lens" available -
        containLensZoom: false,
        lensColour: "white", //colour of the lens background
        lensOpacity: 0.4, //opacity of the lens
        lenszoom: false,
        tint: false, //enable the tinting
        tintColour: "#333", //default tint color, can be anything, red, #ccc, rgb(0,0,0)
        tintOpacity: 0.4, //opacity of the tint
        gallery: false,
        galleryActiveClass: "zoomGalleryActive",
        imageCrossfade: false,
        constrainType: false,  //width or height
        constrainSize: false,  //in pixels the dimensions you want to constrain on
        loadingIcon: false, //http://www.example.com/spinner.gif
        cursor:"default", // user should set to what they want the cursor as, if they have set a click function
        responsive:true,
        onComplete: $.noop,
        onZoomedImageLoaded: function() {},
        onImageSwap: $.noop,
        onImageSwapComplete: $.noop
};
```

})( jQuery, window, document );

Answer (score 0):

Applying the fix mentioned [here](https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/issues/15) fixed the problem for me.

In the minified version, line 11 replace :

```
"px;border-bottom-left-radius: "+String(b.options.lensSize/2+b.options.borderSize)+"px;border-bottom-right-radius: "+String(b.options.lensSize/2+b.options.borderSize)+"px;");b.zoomContainer=d('<div class="zoomContainer" style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);position:absolute;left:'+b.nzOffset.left+"px;top:"+b.nzOffset.top+"px;height:"+b.nzHeight+"px;width:"+b.nzWidth+'px;"></div>');d("body").append(b.zoomContainer);b.options.containLensZoom&&"lens"==b.options.zoomType&&b.zoomContainer.css("overflow",
```

with :

```
"px;border-bottom-left-radius: "+String(b.options.lensSize/2+b.options.borderSize)+"px;border-bottom-right-radius: "+String(b.options.lensSize/2+b.options.borderSize)+"px;");b.zoomContainer=d('<div class="zoomContainer" style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);z-index: 1000;position:absolute;left:'+b.nzOffset.left+"px;top:"+b.nzOffset.top+"px;height:"+b.nzHeight+"px;width:"+b.nzWidth+'px;"></div>');d("body").append(b.zoomContainer);b.options.containLensZoom&&"lens"==b.options.zoomType&&b.zoomContainer.css("overflow",
```